# How to attach the controller $scope variable to $state data in ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller

In my code I want to attach the **$scope.requireLogin** value to **requireLogin** of data. How can I get this in this `.state`?

```
.state('403', {
    url: '/403',
    templateUrl: '403.tmpl.html',
    controller: function($scope, $state, APP, Auth) {
        $scope.app = APP;

        $scope.goHome = function() {
            if(Auth.isAuthenticated()){
                $scope.requireLogin = true;
                $state.go('admin-panel.default.home');
            }
            else{
                $scope.requireLogin = false;
                $state.go('admin-panel.public.home');
            }
        };
    },
    data: {
        requireLogin: $scope.requireLogin
    }
})
```

Can anyone tell me the way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from within your controller.

```
$state.current.data.requireLogin =$scope.requireLogin;
```

Comment: you mean within   this  controller: function($scope, $state, APP, Auth) {})?

Comment: Please see "Attach Custom Data to State Objects" section of https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the data attribute. Use params like params: { theKeyIWantToUse: null }When going to the next state use $state.go("blaroute", { theKeyUsedInParams: theValue } than you can get the value back with $stateParams.theKeyUsedInParams